# intel Atom processor and visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, intel, processor

I wanna buy a notebook that has an atom intel processor

with 1.86 speed

and I want to install visual studio on it, so can it handel VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using a notebook (**Compaq Mini 110c 1111EV**) (**With 2Gb of RAM**) with **windows xp home**. I have installed **Visual Studio 2008** for my work. It **works fine**. With that I mean not with the best speed but with no unrealistic delays. I have also installed **Visual C# 2008 Express**. That works **even better**.

Once I tried **visual studio 2010** But it **was not working to the speed I wanted**. So I don't recommend using it on this. I have even used MATLAB 2008 on this with good performance.
Finally If you hope to run Vista or Windows 7, you may experience slower performance than you can manage.

So finally I would say If you expect to use Visual studio 2008 on Windows XP, you are good to go and anything more than that may make you unhappy.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

> and I want to install visual studio on it, so can it handel VS?

You *can* install VS on it.  It will run.  It will likely not be incredibly fast, as it's a fairly slow processor, and will likely has slow memory and disk access, as well.